# location of separate meshes breaks completely on export, with a black stripe from mesh to center

Tags: animation, mesh, export, .fbx

I have a simple character made with a set of animations in the action editor: a tpose, idle, run and jump.

However, my character consists of multiple objects, the main body, a helmet and a few different pairs of eyes.

In blender, The animations are as they should, with the helmet and eyes having an added constraint of being a child of the head bone.

[image]

However on export, the eyes and helmet are in place of the head, but the head is much lower than it should be, and a black stripe that's visible from the inside of the character's mesh seems to form from his side hip to the center.

[image]

Additionally, when playing animations, the main body moves, but the helmet and eyes stay in place.

The format I export the character to is .FBX

[image]

Comment: you need to specify what format you exported to. most likely your format does not support the blender-specific features you're using.

Comment: I use .FBX when exporting.

Comment: maybe this helps: https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/2.81/addons/import_export/io_scene_fbx.html